How to use a list as a projection in MongoDB
So I am managing a database where we store information of test results for ASICs we are developing. I have one query which will return the numbers of ASICs that did not pass all tests:
list(self.db['TestSummary'].find({'identifier':{'$gt':lowerLim, '$lt':upperLim}, 'summary.passed':{"$lt":passLim}},{'_id':0,'summary':1, 'identifier':1}))

and I want to use this list of ASICs in another query to print out the test results for only the ASICs that failed tests
I have a query that will give me the test result information for all the ASICs in the database:
mydatabase['TestSummary'].find({},{'_id':0, 'identifier':1, "individual_test_outcomes":1})

and I was wondering what was the syntax in the projection argument that would allow me to filter on ASICs that have failed

Please provide some sample input data.
